# MFC-J485DW Brother Printer Installation

Tags: drivers, printing

This printer worked good for a while... but now every doc I sent to print I see the message receiving data and right after cancel printing... any thoughts? Maybe if I remove all brother drivers and reinstall it will works as before. The thing is I'm new to Linux, still crawling and have no clue how to remove all brother drivers.

Comment: It may help if you include the ubuntu version in your question.

Comment: Can this help you https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=as_ot&lang=en&prod=mfc9335cdw_as&faqid=faq00100549_000.  Use dpkg commands on ubuntu.